# symfony 5.4 and doctrine : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set

Tags: doctrine, symfony5.4

i managed to read a book on symfony 5, but i am stuck where the book begins to talk about databases. i 'v been adding this to the .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://amaury:pma@localhost/paracaidismopucon?serverVersion=8&charset=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

where paracaidismopucon is my database.
then when i type:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create -vvv
```

i get the following error:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 117:
                                                                                     
  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set  
                                                                                     

In Exception.php line 28:
                                                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set  
                                                

In Driver.php line 28:
                                                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set  
                                                

doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists]
```

i am a newbie working with symfony...
please help!

i tried to go on different websites to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database) to configure doctrine with multiple databases. I hope that could helps you.

May be the error is caused about that "&charset=utf8mb4_unicode_ci", try to remove it.

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://amaury:pma@localhost/paracaidismopucon?serverVersion=8"
```